# If Condition in Laravel Routes File

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to have if statements in the routes.php file in Laravel 5? I have tried this but does not work:

```
Route::get('/', function()
 {
   if ( Auth::user() )
     Route::get('/', 'PagesController@logged_in_index');
   else
     Route::get('/', 'PagesController@guest_index');
   endif
 });
```

I would prefer this way could work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use Route::group initially instead of Route::get -

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function()
{
    if ( Auth::check() ) // use Auth::check instead of Auth::user
    {
        Route::get('/', 'PagesController@logged_in_index');
    } else{
        Route::get('/', 'PagesController@guest_index');
    }
});
```

But what you'll probably want to do is get rid of the condition in your routes file, and place it inside a generic index method - PagesController@index. Especially if the URL is to remain the same between both routes anyway.

```
public function index()
{
    return Auth::check()
        ? View::make('pages.logged-in-page')
        : View::make('pages.not-logged-in-page');
}
```

Of course, it's up to you which way you think is better.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. When I use the Routes answer, I get this error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be an instance of array, string given`

Comment: This is a tough one @damnkid. It's now defaulting to the guest_index although I am logged in. I guess the routes cant tell if someone is logged in. It assumes im still guest.

Comment: are you using Auth::user() or Auth::check()?

Comment: Stick with Auth::check - it strictly returns a boolean value. Auth::user returns the user model (if logged in), which may be evaluating to false even if you are logged in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73630/discussion-between-damnkid-and-sylar).

Answer (score 0):

you should use **check()** instead **user()**

It's working in laravel 5. I have checked it

```
 Route::get('/', function(){
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            Route::get('/', 'PagesController@logged_in_index');
        } else {
            Route::get('/', 'PagesController@guest_index');
        }
    });
```

other things you did wrong is syntax for **if/else** endif.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the continued support but it's maybe a fault with my set up as nothing works. I'll figure this out then update this question.

Comment: I'm looking to solve the same problem. Auth::check() doesn't work in the router for L5.1. Middleware doesn't work either when you have the same url but different controllers based on login. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
if (Auth::check()){
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@logged_in_index');
} 
else {
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@guest_index');
}
```

In Laravel 5.3.* it works. it works for me so i think it should for you.