# I've got same route url but different controllers

Tags: laravel-5

```
 Route::get('/', 'MyController@index')->name('myCon');
 Route::get('/', 'YourController@index')->name('yourCon');
```

So, i've got two controllers but same url . The second controller overrides the first and shows that i have a variable that's undefined(The data passed from the first controller).

How do I get both the controllers to work while in same url?

Comment: seem impossible if both route the same url, you can check condition for which controller will be called in route file. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222216/if-condition-in-laravel-routes-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Condition in Laravel Routes File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222216/if-condition-in-laravel-routes-file)