# Laravel 7 - Why i can't using the same route in different group of routing?

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

So i have this code in my route :

```
// Facilitator Priviledges
    Route::group(['roles'=>'facilitator'],function(){

        //Material
        Route::get('/material', 'MaterialController@index');
        Route::post('/material', 'MaterialController@store');
        Route::get('/material/{course:id}/create', 'MaterialController@create');
        Route::get('/material/detail/{course:id}', 'MaterialController@show');
        Route::get('/material/{material:id}/edit', 'MaterialController@edit');
        Route::patch('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@update');
        Route::delete('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@destroy');


    });

    //Admin Priviledges
    Route::group(['roles'=>'admin'],function(){
        Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoriesController');  

        //Material
        Route::get('/material', 'MaterialController@index');
        Route::post('/material', 'MaterialController@store');
        Route::get('/material/{course:id}/create', 'MaterialController@create');
        Route::get('/material/detail/{course:id}', 'MaterialController@show');
        Route::get('/material/{material:id}/edit', 'MaterialController@edit');
        Route::patch('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@update');
        Route::delete('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@destroy');
    });
```

It has the same route, in this case, **Material** Route that both admin and facilitator roles can access it, but when the code runs it can be only one role that working fine (I'm using admin) and the other giving error (503) Servive unavailable

Comment: as url remains same, either you can put condition in your view or controller, that do this in case of different roles or add a prefix to each route group,

Comment: because they are the same exact URIs and methods, can only have 1 route registered matching a URI and method combination ... Route groups don't exist, they are only a concept ... all routes are registered individually; there are no concepts of groups after they are registered

Comment: then, where should I using condition for my routing problems ?

Comment: well there are no conditions there, you are just passing an extra piece of data to every route named `'roles'` .... make one group that has `'roles' => ['facilitator', 'admin']` for the overlapping routes ... since you seem to want both roles for those routes, except for that 1 resource in the last group (take it out of the group)  ... Route Groups are just a way to "cascade" configuration

Comment: you could also nest the groups to get the `roles` to cascade, so it will add them together in the inner group, but you would still only have all those overlapping routes in the inner group

Comment: Thanks @lagbox, your syntax seems working in my code, i just modified it like this :
Route::group(['roles'=> ['facilitator','admin']],function(){ ... }

and apparently my middleware could handle two array at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29222661/11206587)

Or you can refer to [Laravel Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-middleware)

or you can simply create your own policy and register it in your middleware.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin', 'facilitator']], function () {
   Route::get('/material', 'MaterialController@index');
   Route::post('/material', 'MaterialController@store');
   Route::get('/material/{course:id}/create', 'MaterialController@create');
   Route::get('/material/detail/{course:id}', 'MaterialController@show');
   Route::get('/material/{material:id}/edit', 'MaterialController@edit');
   Route::patch('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@update');
   Route::delete('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@destroy');
});
```

Comment: i just using this syntax : Route::group(['roles'=> ['facilitator','admin']],function(){ ...}

So i just realize my middleware can handle two array at the same time

Comment: yeah it can also handle a array of functions... where your logic can be executed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the cascading ability of the groups, this is how you would nest them:

```
Route::group(['roles'=>'admin'],function(){
    Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoriesController');  

    Route::group(['roles'=>'facilitator'],function(){
        Route::get('/material', 'MaterialController@index');
        Route::post('/material', 'MaterialController@store');
        Route::get('/material/{course:id}/create', 'MaterialController@create');
        Route::get('/material/detail/{course:id}', 'MaterialController@show');
        Route::get('/material/{material:id}/edit', 'MaterialController@edit');
        Route::patch('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@update');
        Route::delete('/material/{material:id}', 'MaterialController@destroy');
    });
});
```

In the inner group `roles` is `['admin', 'facilitator']`